# How to extract the link that exactly matches the title?

Tags: python, python-re

I want to extract the "bullet train" link from an `href` from an HTML, but I always get the link for "bullet train down".

I have changed the regex a hundred times but it doesn't get what I want.

What I want is the link `/subtitle/sd1638012/bullet-train`

```
def get_subtitles_link():
    title = "Bullet Train"
    subtitles = re.compile('(href="/subtitle/.+?<span)').findall(content)
    print(subtitles)
    #['href="/subtitle/sd1636595/bullet-train-down"><img src="https://cdn.subdl.com/poster      /zqAd0zsic4XIkWFRV7mn09dK1jP.jpg" /></a></div><div class="sc-jFJHMl gPmNjm"><h2 class="sc-bOSxlg jLfqTt"><a class="sc-dXoxLi faLBj" href="/subtitle/sd1636595/bullet-train-down">Bullet Train Down<span', 'href="/subtitle/sd1636595/bullet-train-down"><span', 'href="/subtitle/sd1638012/bullet-train"><img   src="https://cdn.subdl.com/poster/tVxDe01Zy3kZqaZRNiXFGDICdZk.jpg" /></a></div><div class="sc-jFJHMl gPmNjm"><h2 class="sc-bOSxlg jLfqTt"><a class="sc-dXoxLi faLBj" href="/subtitle/sd1638012/bullet-train">Bullet Train<span', 'href="/subtitle/sd1638012/bullet-train"><span', 'href="/subtitle/sd221144/the-bullet-train-shinkansen-daibakuha"><img src="https://cdn.subdl.com/poster/pbsBUvNJJcHRzsv6sVrY1emDDFW.jpg" /></a></div><div class="sc-jFJHMl gPmNjm"><h2 class="sc-bOSxlg jLfqTt"><a class="sc-dXoxLi faLBj"   href="/subtitle/sd221144/the-bullet-train-shinkansen-daibakuha">The Bullet Train (Shinkansen daibakuha)<span', 'href="/subtitle/sd221144/the-bullet-train-shinkansen-daibakuha"><span']

    regx = 'class="sc-jFJHMl gPmNjm"><h2 class=.+?<a.+?href="(.+?)">'+title+'\s+'        
    downloadlink=re.findall(regx,subtitles[0], re.M|re.I)[0]
    print(downloadlink)
    #/subtitle/sd1636595/bullet-train-down
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial challenge you're facing involves attempting to locate specific text that seems to be elusive. To elaborate further, let's delve into the explanation provided below. When you execute the code snippet `print(subtitles[0])`, the output you'll receive is as follows:

`href="/subtitle/sd1636595/bullet-train-down"><img src="https://cdn.subdl.com/poster      /zqAd0zsic4XIkWFRV7mn09dK1jP.jpg" /></a></div><div class="sc-jFJHMl gPmNjm"><h2 class="sc-bOSxlg jLfqTt"><a class="sc-dXoxLi faLBj" href="/subtitle/sd1636595/bullet-train-down">Bullet Train Down<span`

The existing challenge stems from not conducting a comprehensive search through all the text within the list. To address this limitation, consider employing the .join method to convert the list into a  string. This procedure is exemplified as follows:

```
 def get_subtitles_link():
    title = "Bullet Train"
    subtitles = re.compile('(href="/subtitle/.+?<span)').findall(content)
    subtitles = " ".join(subtitles) # here join method to merge the list into a string with space as a delimiter
```

so now if we try to print the result:

```
 def get_subtitles_link():
    title = "Bullet Train"
    subtitles = re.compile('(href="/subtitle/.+?<span)').findall(content)
    subtitles = " ".join(subtitles)
    regx = 'class="sc-jFJHMl gPmNjm"><h2 class=.+?<a.+?href="(.+?)">'+title+'\s+'        
    downloadlink=re.findall(regx,subtitles, re.M|re.I)
    print(downloadlink)
```

The result obtained will be as follows: `['/subtitle/sd1636595/bullet-train-down']`. Now, let's address the current issue. The problem lies within the regex pattern itself. After making some modifications to the pattern, the code will appear as shown below:

```
 def get_subtitles_link():
    title = "Bullet Train"
    subtitles = re.compile('(href="/subtitle/.+?<span)').findall(content)
    subtitles = " ".join(subtitles)
    regx = 'class="sc-jFJHMl gPmNjm"><h2 class=.+<a.+href="(.+?)">'+title+'\s?<'        
    downloadlink=re.findall(regx,subtitles, re.M|re.I)[0]
    print(downloadlink)
```

**Note:**
I  recommend caution when using regex for HTML parsing, as HTML can be quite unpredictable in terms of formatting and structure variations. A minor change in the HTML structure could break the regex pattern. Using a proper HTML parsing library like Beautiful Soup would be a more robust and maintainable solution.